# Unable to set collection view cells to selected when screen first loads

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, collectionview

I basically have a collection view with the days of the week, that is set based on a global array. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the cell will be colored if it is selected in the array. Otherwise it will not be colored. When that cell is selected, it should become colored if it wasn't previously and vice-versa. The problem I'm having is that when I select a colored cell, I have to select it twice to get it to become uncolored. This is because, by default, the `cell.selected`field is false, so one click makes it true, and another click makes it false and gets the desired result. Thats why, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I decided to do `cell.selected = true` if in fact, that day of the week is supposed to be selected, but this doesn't seem to work either. Has anyone come across this issue or have any guidance? Code is below

```
@IBOutlet var daysTableView: UICollectionView!

var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thrusday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

var selected = [0,0,0,0,1,0,1]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    daysTableView.delegate = self
    daysTableView.dataSource = self

    daysTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("days", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DayCell

    cell.day.text = days[indexPath.row]
    if (selected[indexPath.row] == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.selected = false
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        cell.selected = true
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return days.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("selected")
    selected[indexPath.row] = 1
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DayCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    cell.selected = true
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("deselected")
    selected[indexPath.row] = 0
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DayCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.selected = false
}
```

Comment: You should post the section of code that behaves wrongly for us to assist..

Comment: Add some code so we can help you in what you expecting.